# jquery update page when db update

Tags: php, jquery

I've a page that show data inserted in a mysql db; I'd like (if it is possible) that this view page automatically update when a record is added to the db (data are not inserted from the same page or may be inserted from another user).

thanks in advance
ciao h.

Comment: Yes it's possible, what is your question?

Comment: I'd like to have an example or a suggestion on how to do it, thanks again

Comment: @Viper_Sb, I'd also be interested to see your method. Short of having the page refresh or make an AJAX request for updates at a fixed interval I don't know how you would do this.

Comment: You have to check every x amount of time, I doubt you want to put in a method to automatically do this. I didn't mean doing it right when the data was inserted.

Comment: @blcArmadillo this is an interesting project http://ajaxpatterns.org/HTTP_Streaming and something that could solve the problem also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First way (easiest but annoying):
Add a meta refresh to the page and the full page refreshes every x amount of time.

Second way (AJAX):
I'm assuming this is what you want.

- Load default HTML page etc... lets call it index.php
- On above page create a <div> element with style display:none like this

  ```
  <div id="mydata" style="display: none;"></div>
  ```
- Create a PHP page that retrieves and formats the database data and prints it out in x format, i.e a table or p tags. no headers or page specific stuff just data and simple tags
- On index.php put something like this

  ```
  <script type="text/javascript">
      function update() {
          $.ajax({
              url: 'http://www.example.com/getData.php?q=latest',
              success: function(response) {
                  $('#mydata'.html(response);
              }
          });
      }
      // .ready function
      $(function() {
          // do setup stuff here, I think there is a refresh timer or something
          // that you'd use to trigger it every x amount of time
          // i.e something like this
          update();
      });
  </script>
  ```

EDIT: [AJAX HTTP streaming](http://ajaxpatterns.org/HTTP_Streaming) forces data out to users

Answer (score 0):

I know sure on the best method to do this, but and quick-and-easy solution would be to get the total number of rows in your table on page load. Then every *x* seconds use an AJAX script to re-check that table's row count. If it has changed you could have extra logic that then fetches the new rows.

Comment: I think storing the timestamp of the last request, and then checking if there are newer messages makes more sense than checking the total amount of messages (what if someone deletes a message f.e.?)

Comment: Indeed, that's another way of achieving the above. Just simply query the database for any rows after [last update time] if you're storing a time stamp with records.

Answer (score 0):

I was thinking about this last night and realized that node.js (http://nodejs.org/) might be perfect for this if you're looking for an event driven system. There is a good tutorial on getting started using node.js at http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/learning-serverside-javascript-with-node-js/.